# Using AJAX without proxy, JSONP or CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, cors

This script here -> https://github.com/shutterstock/api/blob/master/examples/javascript-jquery/v2.html is entirely front-end that communicates to the ShutterStock api. As far as I know, it's not using a proxy server, and there's no JSONP nor CORS either (because both the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** from the response header and **Origin** from the request header are null). So how is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

> both the Access-Control-Allow-Origin from the response header and Origin from the request header are null

It is using CORS.

The browser says the origin is `null` (indicating that you are loading your HTML document from a `file:` scheme URI and not an HTTP URI) and the server says that the `null` origin is acceptable and allowed to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

The API server sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the same origin as from request header.

Command: `curl 'https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/search' -H 'Origin: http://example.com' --compressed -v`

Output (trimmed):

```
...
> GET /v2/images/search HTTP/1.1
...
> Host: api.shutterstock.com
> Origin: http://example.com
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
...
```